# Email Regex. Is this regex expression appropriate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, email, rubular

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to use a regular expression to validate an email addresses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-to-use-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-addresses)

`\A[\w.-]+\w@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z`

What do you think of the above expression for email validation. Any errors, any loopholes? Thank in advance for the support.

Comment: It's not actually a duplicate. My regular expression should only make sure the email is valid. A valid email could be `a@b.c` where `a` does not allow any symbols apart from `-`,`.` and `_`. `b` contains alphabets and/or numerals and `-`. It should ensure at least one TLD. Check it out with [Rubular](http://www.rubular.com)

Comment: The other question is about a regular expression to make sure an email is valid. How is it not a duplicate?

Comment: Have you tested your regex? It does not even match your example "a@b.c"

Comment: `a@b.c` is a shorthand not what should be matched. I tried to explain the parts in the rest of the comment. @Mechanical snail I checked your link and they have worries that I do not care about. Do you use any of  those in your applications?

Comment: It won't catch RFC-compliant plus-addresses. Please don't reinvent the wheel and create "Yet Another Invalid Validator."

Comment: The only way to see if an email is _really_ valid is to send a confirmation message and see if it arrives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What do you think of the above expression for email validation.

For one, it doesn't accept my address. So, there's obviously a bug in there somewhere. I suggest you read RfC5322 carefully, it describes the valid syntax for addresses quite clearly, although unfortunately it hasn't yet been updated for IDN.

Answer (score 0):

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+(?:[A-Z]{2}|com|org|net|edu|gov|mil|biz|info|mobi|name|aero|asia|jobs|museum)\b
```

Regex from [regular expressions info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html). It should match RFC 2822 standard.